# Jackson json deserialization into Seq[Double] but getting Integers instead of Doubles

Tags: json, scala, jackson, deserialization

I want to deserialize from json using Jackson to get `Seq[Double]`. But the json can be edited and the decimal point can be missing. So I want to deserialize `"list":[1,2.0]` into `Seq(1.0,2.0)`, but Jackson will give me broken list with first item being `Integer` and second one `Double`.

The exception was:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Double  at
>
> scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble(BoxesRunTime.java:114)

Can I tell Jackson to read the string `"1"` as `Double` instead of `Integer`?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

case class SomeDoubles(a: Double, list: Seq[Double])

object TestJackson {
  val jacksonMapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  jacksonMapper.registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule)
  jacksonMapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val test = SomeDoubles(1.0, Seq(1.0, 2.0))

    println(jacksonMapper.writeValueAsString(test)) // {"a":1.0,"list":[1.0,2.0]}

    val json = """{"a":1,"list":[1,2.0]}""" // changing value 1.0 into 1

    val test2 = jacksonMapper.readValue[SomeDoubles](json) // it deserializes list into Integer and Double
    println(test2) // SomeDoubles(1.0,List(1, 2.0)) ... so the first item in list is already Integer and not Double
    val aValue = test2.a
    println(aValue) // 1.0
    val firstListedValue = test2.list.head
    println(firstListedValue) // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `jakson` does not parse `List` or `Seq` well.

For your case, the code runs well with following modifications using `Array` instead of `List` or `Seq`:

```scala
// line 6: List --> Array
case class SomeDoubles(a: Double, list: Array[Double])

// line 14:
val test = SomeDoubles(1.0, Array(1.0, 2.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of issue

try `case class SomeDoubles(a: java.lang.Double, list: Seq[java.lang.Double])`

and get back to scala Double after the deserialisation if needed, with `.map(_.toDouble)` for example